# D3 Sliders - Retrieving & Showing Values

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a basic (vertical) slider in D3 as follows:

```
 var line = canvas.append("line")
  .attr("y1", y1)
  .attr("y2", y2)
  .attr("x1", x)
  .attr("x2", x)
  .style("stroke", "black")
  .style("stroke-linecap", "round")
  .style("stroke-width", 5);

var circle = canvas.append("circle")
  .attr("r", radius)
  .attr("cy", function(d) { == return d.y; })
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
  .style("cursor", "ew-resize")
  .call(drag);
```

Where the function call drag is as follows:

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
  .origin(function(d) { return d; })
  .on("drag", dragmove);
```

And this call to dragmove is the following:

```
function dragmove(d) {
  var y = d3.event.y;
  y = y < y1 ? y1 : y > y2 ? y2 : y;
  d.y = y;
  authorMin = (y-y1)/(y2-y1);
  circle.attr("cy", y);
}
```

What I need to to retrieve the value of the slider (which I assume will be cy in this case) and show this on the screen next to the circle. I have adding a variable set in the dragmove function based on the y of that block. This variable is then used as the "text" element appended to the canvas (where var canvas = d3.select("svg")).

This does not seem to show anything on the screen and even so, I am not sure how to go about updating the value shown next to the circle based on its position (and replacing the old value by the latest one.

I would want the value to be a percentage from 0-100, so looking at my code for the line, this would look something like ((y-y1)/(y2-y1))*100. Do I need code both in the circle element and in the dragmove function? I am not sure if I am overthinking this, so any help or hints you may have would be really helpful. Apologies if this is a simple solution as I am very new to D3!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you already have the slider, please share the working code. Thus, we only have the trouble of adding the text with the value.

Comment: I have created a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qbnzocop/10/) that you can edit. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Your fiddle is just the code you copy/pasted above. It's **not** a working code.

Comment: Can you try the link again now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the position of the circle, just use a getter...

```
var value = circle.attr("cy");
```

And update a text variable (here named `text`) with the math to get the percentage:

```
text.text("Value: " + ~~(100*(value-y1)/(y2-y1)) + "%")
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var width = 50;
 var height = 300;
  
  var canvas = d3.select("svg")
   .attr("width", 1600)
   .attr("height", 1000)
   .datum({
     x: width / 2,
     y: height / 2,
   });
    
 var radius = 10;
 var margin = 10;
 var y1 = margin;
 var y2 = height - margin;
 var x = width / 2;

 var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
   .origin(function(d) {
     return d;
   })
   .on("drag", dragmove);
    
  var text = canvas.append("text")
   .attr("x", 50)
    .attr("y", height/2)
    .text("Value: 50%")

 var line = canvas.append("line")
   .attr("y1", y1)
   .attr("y2", y2)
   .attr("x1", x)
   .attr("x2", x)
   .style("stroke", "black")
   .style("stroke-linecap", "round")
   .style("stroke-width", 5);

 var circle = canvas.append("circle")
   .attr("r", radius)
   .attr("cy", function(d) {
     return d.y;
   })
   .attr("cx", function(d) {
     return d.x;
   })
   .style("cursor", "ew-resize")
   .call(drag);
    
   function dragmove(d) {
   var y = d3.event.y;
   y = y < y1 ? y1 : y > y2 ? y2 : y;
   d.y = y;
   circle.attr("cy", y);
    var value = circle.attr("cy");
    text.text("Value: " + ~~(100*(value-y1)/(y2-y1)) + "%")
 }
```

```html
<svg></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That seems to do the job. Thank you for your help! And sorry for providing the wrong link before.